# How to check if a number comes before another in a List

Tags: list, python-3.x, find

How can I go about checking if an element comes before another in a list?

For example:

how can I check if 5 comes before 12 in a list:

```
li = [1,2,3,7,4,5,10,8,9,12,11]
```

Is there an built-in Python function that can allow me to do that?

Comment: umm `li.index(5) < li.index(12)` ?

Comment: what about `[1,12,3,4,5,6,12,1,2,3,5]` Is this the case how this should be considered is here 5 before 12

Answer (score 6):

Here ya go:

```
>>> li = [1,2,3,7,4,5,10,8,9,12,11]
>>> li.index(5) > li.index(12)    # 5 comes after 12
False
>>> li.index(5) < li.index(12)    # 5 comes before 12
True
>>>
>>> help(list.index)
Help on method_descriptor:

index(...)
    L.index(value, [start, [stop]]) -> integer -- return first index of value.
    Raises ValueError if the value is not present.

>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if li.index(5) < li.index(12):
   print "came before"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `list`'s inbuilt `index` function:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,7,3,5,21,8,44,16,12]
>>> l.index(5) > l.index(12)
False
>>> l.index(5) < l.index(12)
True
>>>
```

`index` returns the index of the first occurrence of a number. An example of how `index` works:

```
>>> t = (0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2)
>>> t.index(3)
3
>>> t.index(0)
0
```

Note that there are *two* `0`s here.

Comment: ?  You mean `list`'s built-in index function.

Comment: @iCodez You're right. I always using it with a string object, so I forget sometimes :P

Answer (score -3):

I don't know python, but generally arrays and lists in programming languages use a zero-based index to identify each element. You usually can access each element via their index in the using the format li[index] = element. For example:

```
let li = [1,2,3,7,4,5,10,8,9,12,11]

li[0] = 1;
li[1] = 2;
li[2] = 3;
li[3] = 7;
li[4] = 4;
```

etc. Many systems will also have an IndexOf() method that will allow you to determine the index of an element using a format similar to li.IndexOf(element). This feature can be used in your example such as:

```
Boolean Is_5_B4_12 = li.IndexOf(5) < li.IndexOf(12);
```

If python does not have such a feature, you can easily create one yourself by using a loop and an incrementor. Something similar to this would work:

```
Function IndexOf(integer element)
    integer index = 0;
    Do While index < len(li) //len() is a function that specifies the number of elements in the list
        if li[index] == element then return index;
        index = index + 1;
    Loop
End Function
```

I hope this answers your question! Regards - yisrael lax